# Restructure tables with media queries

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I have a table with four columns and two rows, as follows:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td> A </td>
    <td> B </td>
    <td> C </td>
    <td> D </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> E </td>
    <td> F </td>
    <td> G </td>
    <td> H </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Using a `media` query, such as `@media (max-width: 800px)`, I want to restructure this table to instead have two columns and four rows, e.g:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td> A </td>
    <td> B </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> C </td>
    <td> D </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> E </td>
    <td> F </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> G </td>
    <td> H </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Is this possible? Solutions in JavaScript are also welcome if, which I assume to be the case, this cannot be done with mere CSS.

Comment: Take a look at this [Media Queries Data Tables](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/)

Comment: if you want to do this as a table, then you are going to have to use JS or use pseudo-elements as @Paul suggests. If you can use divs you could possibly go for a pure CSS option.

Comment: You can use CSS to visually get the same result but the physical underlying table structure should not be touched through CSS (assuming it is possible) - If you don't have control over the original code that generates the initial table it looks like you might need to create a script based "mapper" that converts the table "structure A" into "structure B" if you must physically change the structure in the DOM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pure CSS**

Changing the appearance using `float`s and `nth-child`.

```
td { float:left; display:inline-block; }
td:nth-child(3) {
  clear:both;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hks5d6th/2/

**JavaScript**

Looping through all applicable columns and use the modulus operator to determine where to split out into new rows.

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0],
  columns = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('td')),
  newTable = document.createElement('table'), html;

columns.forEach(function(next, idx) {
  if (idx % 2 === 0 || idx === 0) {
    html += '<tr>' + next.outerHTML;
    return;
  }
  html += next.outerHTML + '</tr>';
});

newTable.innerHTML = html;
table.replaceWith(newTable);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hks5d6th/1/

Comment: Thanks very much. I read both methods but I not advanced enough to understand the JS on :') The CSS one works great though!

Comment: Just one question: would the pure css method still work with an odd number of columns (i.e three columns)?

Comment: this only works cause there are four columns per row. if you wanted it to work every three columns you'd need six columns per row, then it'd be every `nth-child(4)` to have three column rows ...

Comment: But can you change a three column table to a two column table?